# Como obtener datos al Recorrer un GridView For Each vb.net asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net, gridview

Quiero obtener los datos que voy recorriendo en un GridView

```
For Each Fila As GridViewRow In GCURSO.Rows
     ceEvaluacion.CursoAlumno = Fila.Cells(0).ToString
Next
```

Pero al usar `Fila.Cells(0).ToString` no obtengo el dato.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

he encontrado una solución a mi problema, la comparto y espero les sea de utilidad:

Dado a que el valor que necesitaba captar estaba en una columna oculta y strVariable  = Fila.Cells(1).Text.ToString solo captura valores de columnas que se muestran agregue al Grid la propiedad DataKeyNames="Columna Id" y en el For Each capto el valor strVariable = Me.GridView.DataKeys(Fila.RowIndex).Value

Queda así

```
For Each Fila As GridViewRow In GCURSO.Rows

   strVariable = Me.GridView.DataKeys(Fila.RowIndex).Value

next
```

Saludos y Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debrias hacerlo de esta manera:

```
 For Each Fila As DataGridViewRow In GCURSO.Rows
     ceEvaluacion.CursoAlumno = Fila.Cells(0).Value
Next
```

Estas recorriendo un `GridViewRow` y debes ser `DataGridViewRow`  además te está faltando el `.Value` de la celda.  `Fila.Cells(0).Value`

Comment: Al ponerle Fila.Cells(0).Value.ToString me indica que value no es miembro de System.web.UI.WebControls.TableCell

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero al poner  ceEvaluacion.CursoAlumno = Fila.Cells(1).Text.ToString no me caputura ningun valor, solo me pone ""

Comment: @JonathanValle prueba ahora.

Comment: Funciona bien, gracias, pero me he percatado que las celdas .visible = false no se pueden capturar, hay alguna manera para hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each Fila  In GCURSO.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
     ceEvaluacion.CursoAlumno = Fila.Cells("nombredecolumna").Value.ToString()
Next
```

Aunque no entiendo porqué recorres todas las filas y le asignas su primer columna a una sola variable, así solo estas guardando la última fila pues las anteriores de pierden.

Te recomiendo que en vez de usar directamente el número de columna, hagas referencia al nombre de la columna, así, si agregas después otra columna al principio, no te de error